# Can I create parser classes on container initialization?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm using docker and docker-compose to easily setup parser-server for a project using the `parseplatform/parse-server` image.

So far everything runs perfectly and I can go and manually add the classes I need for the app via the parse-dashboard, but I would like to automate this.

Is there any way to pass a `schema` on parse first run to populate the database with the required classes? I'm keeping `PARSE_SERVER_ALLOW_CLIENT_CLASS_CREATION` as false.

Any ENV variables that I'm not aware of? Is the only alternative pulling the repo and building the image with some custom config?

As far my search went I can't find any info on the subject. Parse seems to be a very powerful tool, but the docs tend to be very simplistic as far I've seen.

Thanks for any input/help.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: parse-mongo
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD

  parse:
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    container_name: parse-server
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    links:
      - mongodb:mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID
      - PARSE_SERVER_APP_NAME
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI
      - PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_GRAPHQL
      - PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_PLAYGROUND
      - PARSE_SERVER_ALLOW_CLIENT_CLASS_CREATION
```

.env

```
# MONGO DB
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=###
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=###

# PARSE SERVER
PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=###
PARSE_SERVER_APP_NAME=###
PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=###
PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI="mongodb://${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}:${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}@mongo:27017"
PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_GRAPHQL=1
PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_PLAYGROUND=1
PARSE_SERVER_ALLOW_CLIENT_CLASS_CREATION=0
```

Comment: please, share what you have tried so far. Docker-compose file, commands you ran, link, so that your issue could be reproducible

Comment: @rok I can edit the question and add the docker-compose, but it is not relevant for the question... parse set ups perfectly and create its default classes without any issue, I can go and manually add my own via the dashboard. I'm looking for a way to automate this process.

Comment: I'd try to write a node.js script that uses Parse JS SDK to create the schema. You can call the script in your DockerFile entry point.